# how to include huge javascript js file in html?

Tags: javascript, json, zip

I have a JavaScript file that is 18 megabytes. It is just a JSON array I need.

To deliver this huge JSON.js file to the client, the browser takes 18 seconds, assuming the user's Internet speed is about 1 megabyte/second, which is common.

To open a page uses about 18 seconds! It is unacceptable user experience. 
I have zip it to a json.zip which is 3MB, reducing 83% of size, which means reducing 83% of bandwidth, which will take 3 seconds for user to download.

3 seconds is much better user experience.

Here is problem, how could I use `<script>` tag in HTML to include this jsonjs.zip file?

include tag in browser will NOT recognize a '.zip' file.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a js library for manipulating zip files, such as [jszip](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/)

However, I would consider splitting the data into chunks - do all users really need all 18mb at once? What if you loaded some of it on-demand? Can the data in the json be simplified?

Answer (score 0):

I would break it up into smaller json files and load via XHR if possible, especially if it JSON content type. :)

Answer (score 0):

After 8 hours searching and testing, I made it.

[zip.js](https://gildas-lormeau.github.io/zip.js/) is what you need.

[zip.js  api doc](http://gildas-lormeau.github.io/zip.js/core-api.html)

1) download and add all  zip.js, z-worker.js, deflate.js, inflate.js etc..... in your project ( you must add all related files, otherwise will error out later)

2) html file, add script tag, I use relative path to the current html page

```
<!-- ********* zip.js *********** -->

    <script src="../js/lib/zipjs/zip.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- you must add this, to use zip.HttpReader later -->
    <script src="../js/lib/zipjs/zip-ext.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 

 <!-- ********* End ******** zip.js *********** -->
```

3) in your javascript file do this:

```
           //------------------- zip.js -----------------------------------






                var _static_site_zip_uri = 'http://localhost:10/data/json2tree/hub.site.static.data.js.zip'




                zip.workerScriptsPath = "../js/lib/zipjs/";



                //https://github.com/gildas-lormeau/zip.js/issues/93

                zip.createReader(new zip.HttpReader(_static_site_zip_uri), 
                                                                           function(zipReader){


                                                               zipReader.getEntries(function(entries){
                                                                   if (entries.length) {

                                                                        // get first entry content as text
                                                                        entries[0].getData(new zip.TextWriter(), function(text) {
                                                                          // text contains the entry data as a String
                                                                         // console.log(text);





                                                                           //..........load into json-viewer,  unzipped text is string .........
                                                                                    input = JSON.parse(text);

                                                                                    // init load
                                                                                    $('#json-renderer').jsonViewer(input, options);
                                                                            //.......... End ....... load into json-viewer,  unzipped text is string .........







                                                                          // close the zip reader
                                                                          zipReader.close(function() {
                                                                            // onclose callback
                                                                          });

                                                                        }, function(current, total) {
                                                                          // onprogress callback

                                                                           // console.log('current-', current)
                                                                           //  console.log('total-', total)
                                                                        });
                                                                      }
                                                                    });
                                                                  }, function(zipreader_error) {
                                                                    // onerror callback
                                                                    console.log('zipreader_error --->',zipreader_error)
                                                                  });





           //------------------- End ---------------  zip.js -----------------------------------
```

4). Done.

remember my zip file is a array [{},{}], so use json.parse(text)